# How to read a .csv file in mulesoft

Tags: csv, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am trying to read a csv file in mulesoft, can one tell me how to do that ? How to tell mulesoft which file to read ?

Answer (score 3):

Everyone is talking about transforming but you are asking how to read.

You will need the File connector, or FTP, SFTP or some SaaS applications maybe.

You can find an example of reading a CSV file with the File connector in Mule here:

https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/importing-csv-into-mongodb

You will specify a path where Mule should poll for files, polling frequency and you can specify a pattern for which files Mule should look with a regex pattern.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/file-connector

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you can do this

1) Using Mule Datamapper component (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/datamapper-flat-to-structured-and-structured-to-flat-mapping)

2) Java component that uses apachi poi api to read CSV file and process.

Thanks & Regards,

Ramakrishna N

Comment: Actually my scenario is, I have flat file (comma delimited) with 2 columns one Language & Code. I want to split this data into 2 flat files asper the two language codes (similar language code and the subsequent data in same files). 

My approach was reading it through single source flat file, putting a choice transformation & splitting them into 2. Now I am unable to understand this that how to let mulesoft know it is a tab delimited or comma etc.

Answer (score 1):

To read a file follow the below steps:

> Drag the File endpoint to your flow. 
>   click the file endpoint and browse the path under basic settings
>   Provide file name in the Move to pattern field. 
>   optionally you can configure the polling frequency and file age.

Now as your flow is configured to read the file and you can apply dataweave/transformers to manipulate your data in payload.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can read a csv file by setting the reader-property as given below in transform component.

```
   <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
             <dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data\list_csv.csv" mimeType="application/csv">
                 <dw:reader-property name="separator" value="|"/>
                 <dw:reader-property name="header" value="false" />
             </dw:input-payload>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use DataWeave, this depends on the version of the Mule ESB Runtime that you are using.

Since 3.7.0 EE DataMapper has been deprecated and replaced by DataWeave

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation

If you are using an Enterprise version prior to 3.7 you can use DataMapper.

If you are using a Community Runtime you will have to use a Java Component and create the custom code to read it.

Answer (score 0):

First transform tge csv file to xml.After that you have to use xslt .Inside Xslt you can group based on the languagcode.then send it to file.

Regards 
Prashanth A

Answer (score 0):

use a file connector.
add file regex expression which format of file you want to read

Answer (score 0):

You can find **File Name Regex Filter** in General Tab of File property. It is used to configure a filter to restrict the files being processed.
You can refer the following link for specifying filter based on your requirement.

Please refer the following link to know how to write Regex Filter :
[syntax for filename-regex-filter pattern in mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786955/syntax-for-filename-regex-filter-pattern-in-mule)

Answer (score 0):

Drag the endpoint to your flow. click the file endpoint and browse the path under basic settings Provide file name in the Move to pattern field. optionally you can configure the polling frequency and file age.

Answer (score 0):

use transform message component and define metadata add the csv configurations. you can change the header and the limiters and splitters there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a ffd or flat file definition as a scheme definition, set this as metadata of the listener, use dataweave to read the data, and implement your business logic.

For more detailed implementation, please go through this link:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-flat-file-schemas

Answer (score -1):

After determining the file name you can use either parse template  or Groovy script to read the file.

```
1. <parse-template location="my-resurce.txt" doc:name="Load resource as a String"/>
2. <scripting:component doc:name="Get file">                                        
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[new File('C:/project/src/main/resources/test.csv').getText('UTF-8')]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

Below link has more details about the different approaches to choose from.
[mule read single file from classpath during flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203458/mule-read-single-file-from-classpath-during-flow)